# Tensorflow with nodejs model.save Not Work

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js

In my code:

```
async function saveModel(model) {
  try {
       await model.save('file:///model/modelo');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}


....
await saveModel(model);
```

Error:
`ValueError: Cannot find any save handlers for URL 'file:///model/modelo'`

File structures

```
model
node_modules
package.json
file.js
```

Model structure

```
<ref *1> Sequential {
  _callHook: null,
  _addedWeightNames: [],
  _stateful: false,
  id: 0,
  activityRegularizer: null,
  inputSpec: null,
  supportsMasking: false,
  _trainableWeights: [],
  _nonTrainableWeights: [],
  _losses: [],
  _updates: [],
  _built: true,
  inboundNodes: [
    Node {
      callArgs: undefined,
      id: 3,
      outboundLayer: [Circular *1],
      inboundLayers: [],
      nodeIndices: [],
      tensorIndices: [],
      inputTensors: [Array],
      outputTensors: [Array],
      inputMasks: [Array],
      outputMasks: [Array],
      inputShapes: [Array],
      outputShapes: [Array]
    }
  ],
  outboundNodes: [],
  ......
}
```

I've also tested changing the file:/// format to the one indicated in the documentation: localstorage and downloads, but it didn't work because the same error occurs